# Caption centering does not work

Tags: horizontal-alignment, captions, subcaption

I am using `subcaption` package to plot subfloats in my report. However, the caption for subfigures are not centered. Here is what I have done:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report}
\usepackage{epsfig,cite,amsfonts,amssymb,psfrag,balance}
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{newlfont}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{morefloats}

\begin{subfigure}{0.33\textwidth}
    \centering
    \psfrag{lambda}[][][1.5]{$\log_{10} (\lambda)$}
    \psfrag{N}[][][1.5]{Channel Noise Power, $N$}
    \resizebox{8cm}{!}{\epsfbox{P3_N_vary.eps}}
    \caption{Achievable}
    \label{fig:p3_graph1}
\end{subfigure}
\hspace{2.5cm}
\begin{subfigure}{0.33\textwidth}
    \centering
    \psfrag{lambda}[][][1.5]{$\log_{10} (\lambda)$}
    \psfrag{Ps}[][][1.5]{Encoder transmit power, $\ps$}
    \resizebox{8cm}{!}{\epsfbox{P3_ps_vary.eps}}
    \caption{Achievable }
    \label{fig:p3_graph2}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{}
\end{figure}
```

Am I missing something here? Can somebody help me out please?

Comment: your MWE doesn't compile- please fix it, and remove any unnecessary packages :)

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you're using a "standard" paper size (either letterpaper or A4) and "normal" horizontal margins (ca. 1"), your document's `\textwidth` parameter will be equal to roughly 6" (15cm). You allocate an overall width to each `subfigure` environments of `0.33\textwidth`, which works out to about 2" (**5cm**). Yet, via the `\resizebox` instructions, you specify a display width of **8cm** for the included graphics. These parameters are not mutually consistent, and thus LaTeX can't perform the centering as requested.

To fix up the problem, you may try applying the following changes: (i) specify widths of each subfigure of `0.45\textwidth` instead `0.33\textwidth`, (ii) use `\linewidth` instead of `8cm` as the first argument of the `\resizebox` instructions, and (iii) replace the instruction `\hspace{2.5cm}` with `\hspace{\fill}`.